# MySQL table structure of a custom form

Tags: php, mysql, yaml, custom-fields

I am currently developing a **customizable form** script, and my users will be able to create new fields into their custom forms.

How to make a MySQL table structure for it? And if you know YAML, it would be helpful?

Answer (score 2):

A rough outline...

### Table: user

- user_id
- email_address
- password

### Table: form

- form_id
- user_id
- title
- active

### Table: field

- field_id
- form_id
- name
- type

This is a simple schema based on One User having Multiple Forms, and One Form having Multiple Fields. You can, of course, add fields to these suggested fields, really the only essential fields are the ones ending in "_id".

Comment: Thank you Lucanos, that gave me an idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
User:
  columns:
    user_id:  { type: integer, primary: true, notnull: true }
    email:    { type: string(80) }
    password: { type: string(80) }

Form:
  columns:
    form_id:   { type: integer, primary: true, notnull: true }
    user_id:   { type: integer, notnull: true }
    title:     { type: string(80) }
    is_active: { type: boolean, notnull: true, default: 1 }
  relations:
    User:      { onDelete: CASCADE, local: user_id, foreign: user_id, foreignAlias: Forms }

Field:
  columns:
    field_id:    { type: integer, primary: true, notnull: true }
    form_id:     { type: integer, notnull: true }
    field_name:  { type: string(80) }
    field_type:  { type: enum, values: [ String, Integer, Float, LongText, Boolean] }
    field_value: { type: string(80) }
  relations:
    Form:        { onDelete: CASCADE, local: form_id, foreign: form_id, foreignAlias: Fields }
```

The MySQL database generated by above YAML:

> CREATE TABLE `field` (
> `field_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
> `form_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
> `field_name` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
> `field_type` enum('String','Integer','Float','LongText','Boolean') DEFAULT NULL,
> `field_value` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY (`field_id`),
> KEY `form_id_idx` (`form_id`),
> CONSTRAINT `field_form_id_form_form_id` FOREIGN KEY (`form_id`) REFERENCES `form` (`form_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
>
> CREATE TABLE `form` (
> `form_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
> `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
> `title` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
> `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
> PRIMARY KEY (`form_id`),
> KEY `user_id_idx` (`user_id`),
> CONSTRAINT `form_user_id_user_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
>
> CREATE TABLE `user` (
> `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
> `email` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
> `password` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: I think, you use this only for schema (or structure) of form, right? How to use this?

Comment: I found a tutorial. I think, you meant that: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/yaml-schema-files/en

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the **users** to change the table structure?  This would mean that you'd need to execute a mysql alter query, maybe like

```
 ALTER TABLE the_table DROP COLUMN one_column
```

or

```
 ALTER TABLE the_table ADD COLUMN another_column
```

And you'd want to wrap this in something that checked the table structure before executing this query.  Having run the alter table queries you could then do the data management.

I think the best way to check the table structure before altering it would be to view the system tables

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, is_nullable, data_type, character_maximum_length
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
WHERE table_name = 'the_table'
```

This will return the information about all the columns in this table.

Does this help?

Comment: No, I don't need the users to change table structure. I meant customizable forms. Thanks though Jim! Any advice is always welcomed in my realm.